# Not able to delete lowest score from array of documents in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

This is how my collection looks:

```
db.students.find({_id:100}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : 100,
    "name" : "Demarcus Audette",
    "scores" : [
        {
            "type" : "exam",
            "score" : 30.61740640636871
        },
        {
            "type" : "quiz",
            "score" : 14.23233821353732
        },
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 31.41421298576332
        },
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 30.09304792394713
        }
    ]
}
```

I am executing the following 2 queries on Mongo shell:

```
x=db.students.aggregate( [{ "$unwind":"$scores" },{"$match":{"scores.type":"homework"}},{ "$group":{"_id":"$_id","minscore":{"$min":"$scores.score" }}} ] )
```

and the next one is:

```
for (var a in x["a"]) { db.students.update( { "_id":a["_id"] },{"$pull":{"scores":{"score":a["minscore"]}}} ) }
```

I am able to see the min score list, but when I execute the second query nothing seems to be deleted. I know there is a logical error. I tried to read on the posts here, but I couldn't get pas through it. I just wanted to know where was I going wrong.

Comment: This is homework from week 4 in MongoDB for java developers course !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code worked for me.

```
var x=db.students.aggregate( [{ "$unwind":"$scores" },{"$match":{"scores.type":"homework"}},{"$group":{"_id":"$_id","minscore":{"$min":"$scores.score" }}} ] );

var doc = x.hasNext() ? x.next() : null;

x.forEach(function(doc){
    db.students.update( { "_id": doc._id }, { "$pull": { "scores" : { "score":doc.minscore, "type":"homework"} } } );
});
```

Answer (score 5):

There are several problems in your for loop - though your aggregation looks good.

Your result document "x" contains an array field "result".  You want to iterate over the documents in that array.  The for loop syntax you have won't set a to values in the array but rather to indexes in the array.  Better and clearer would be to use forEach loop syntax:

```
x.result.forEach(function(doc) {
   db.students.update( { "_id": doc._id }, 
                       { "$pull": { "scores" : { 
                                          "score":doc.minscore, 
                                          "type":"homework"
                       } } } 
   );
});
```

Your update statement wasn't quite accurate either - you want to make sure you pull only the *homework* with the lowest score - what if the same student had a single exam which was also the same score as their lowest homework?  Your syntax would pull all subdocuments which have the score equal to minscore!

That one is easy to fix (and I show you the syntax you need to use to only pull homework subdocuments), but remember that [$pull will pull **all** values](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull) that match the query, and if there was only one homework then it's the minscore and it will get pulled.   And if there were two homework scores but they were equal, they will **both** get pulled!  Something to consider.

Comment: this answer was back in MongoDB 2.4 days - aggregation returned a single document back then which contained a field result which was an array.

Answer (score 2):

Use the code below to delete the lowest score. The Aggregation code is alright.

```
x=db.students.aggregate( [{ "$unwind":"$scores" },{"$match":{"scores.type":"homework"}},{ "$group":{"_id":"$_id","minscore":{"$min":"$scores.score" }}} ] );

var doc = myCursor.hasNext() ? x.next() : null;

x.forEach(function(doc) {db.students.update( { "_id": doc._id }, { "$pull": { "scores" : { 
"score":doc.minscore, "type":"homework"} } } );
```

After running the above code at the MongoShell - 
db.students.find.pretty();
you will get the records in the document like this -

```
{
    "_id" : 100,
    "name" : "Demarcus Audette",
    "scores" : [
        {
            "type" : "exam",
            "score" : 30.61740640636871
        },
        {
            "type" : "quiz",
            "score" : 14.23233821353732
        },
        {
            "type" : "homework",
            "score" : 31.41421298576332
        },
    ]
}
```

The lowest score of type: "homework" will be deleted from every record set.

Comment: there is a typo in the above code: the line:                                                  var doc = myCursor.hasNext() ? x.next() : null; should read:                       var doc = x.hasNext() ? x.next() : null;

Comment: The line var doc = myCursor.hasNext() ? x.next() : null; is not needed remove it and the code will work

Comment: There are some typos and syntax errors in the solution. Please use below statements. 
var x=db.students.aggregate( [{ "$unwind":"$scores" },{"$match":{"scores.type":"homework"}},{"$group":{"_id":"$_id","minscore":{"$min":"$scores.score" }}} ] );

var doc = x.hasNext() ? x.next() : null;

x.forEach(function(doc){
 db.students.update( { "_id": doc._id }, { "$pull": { "scores" : { "score":doc.minscore, "type":"homework"} } } );
});

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you do:

```
x = db.students.aggregate([
  { "$unwind":"$scores" },
  {"$match":{
    "scores.type":"homework"
  }},
  { 
    "$group":{
       "_id":"$_id",
       "minscore":{"$min":"$scores.score" }}
    }
]);
```

your result is in the form:

```
{
  result : [{
    "_id" : 100,
    "minscore" : 30.09304792394713
  }],
  ok : 1
}
```

So there is no `x["a"]` there and you need to write `x['result']`.

**P.S.** if you are doing homework questions, you should write about it.

Comment: did you try the code?  there are multiple things that are wrong there, and just changing "a" to "result" won't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer the worked with me, based on the combination of the other answers.

```
x = db.students.aggregate([
  { "$unwind":"$scores" },
  {"$match":{
    "scores.type":"homework"
  }},
  { 
    "$group":{
       "_id":"$_id",
       "minscore":{"$min":"$scores.score" }}
    }
]);



x.result.forEach(function(doc) {db.students.update( { "_id": doc._id },                         { "$pull": { "scores" : {
               "score":doc.minscore,"type":"homework" } } }); });
```